# What's better - drawing every interval that the window updates, or drawing when necessary and updating when drawing?

Tags: opengl, sfml, c++

So what's better?

In case the title is a bit confusing I mean:

1) Drawing every window update interval. For example, for a 60FPS window, every 17 milliseconds. For example:

```
window.setFramerateLimit(60); //Update every 17 milliseconds for 60FPS
while(window.isOpen()) {
window.display();
}
```

Or

2) Drawing when you need to (for example, when a sprite moves) and displaying it straight after.
For example:

```
void func(sf::RenderWindow& window) {
window.draw(sf::Sprite()); //Whatever you're drawing
window.display();
}
```

Or is there a much better way?

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You should draw everything, and swap the buffer (display), at most once per frame (usually 1/60th second).

You should definitely *not* call window.display() more than once per frame.

If nothing at all has moved, you might choose to skip drawing and displaying entirely for that frame, especially on a mobile device to conserve power. On a desktop, typically, may as well draw every frame, to keep the loading predictable.

Last note -- your game logic updates might or might not also be at the same 1/60th per second update. Easiest if they are, if possible.